# Execute SSIS using DTExec.exe

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hi I have issues on how to excute this SSIS. This SSIS is working when I excute with VStudio.But, I got problem with comand line utility.

My command :
DTExec.exe /F / ATSEVENTPRNT_C_LD.dtsx

Return msg(with 3 Warning BUT success):
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).

My flat file connection using this format :
\\c$\Logfile grabber\logs\Events\eventsData.txt

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem is. The DTSER_SUCCESS return value means the package executed succesfully. I don't see any warning messages in your question.

For automated execution, consider uploading the package into SQL Server's MSDB and then executing it as a Scheduled Job in the SQL Server Agent.